# Azure Datafacory - Data validation

Tags: validation, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to move data from Azure Blob storage to Documentdb. For this I have created a datafactory with copy activity, which does the work. However, I need to check whether the record exists in the database before inserting, which does not happen with copy activity (atleast as per my knowledge). Have not come across any activity or means to validate except for a custom activity. Can someone suggest if whether this is possible or if there is any other way to achieve it.

Comment: If you are keeping the same GUIDs (does Blob storage even use GUIDs?) then you can do an upsert every time and not worry about it. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

Does https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-documentdb-connector/#appendix help answer your Q? 
If records have an "ID" field and the copy operation tries to insert a record with the same ID, the copy operation throws an error.

Comment: There won't be any id field and it is generated while importing. We have to check based on a combination of few fields for uniqueness before inserting. Thanks for your reply. We are left with no option for now other than checking each row to make sure the data is not repeated.